# Correct use of hyphens in "we offer same day, on site service calls"

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, modifiers

What would be the correct hyphenation (if any) for the following sentence?

> We offer same day, on site service calls.

I was thinking of hyphenating "on-site", but I cannot think why "same day" would not be hyphenated also (other than the fact it looks wrong).

Any guidance would be much appreciated, as this is going on the front page of my business website.

Answer (score 5):

Both *same day* and *on site* modify the noun *service calls*.

Furthermore, *same day* is a remote reference for *service calls*, unlike *on site*, which is immediately before it. All the more reason for *same day* to be hyphenated.

> We offer **same-day, on-site** service calls.

Answer (score 3):

Yes to both same-day and on-site.

Comment: Yes, but why? (I might then up vote you).

Answer (score 3):

These are compound adjectives and should be hyphenated.

The reason for this is that they don't make sense if one part of the adjective is removed.

The following example has a list of unconnected adjectives and you could remove any of them and the sentence would still be grammatically correct:

> We offer professional, friendly and reliable service calls.

That is not true for unhyphentated compound adjectives:
 *We offer day, site service calls.*

Hyphenating them also avoids potential confusion. Your sentence is quite straightforward but compare these, which have very different meanings:

> We ordered timber in twenty-four metre lengths
>   We ordered timber in twenty four-metre lengths

Comment: Compound adjectives are not always hyphenated, several examples exist in the writings of respected authors. There's has been a question or two about this right here on ELU earlier.